# SQL trace events list

Tags: sql-server, profiler

This [german msdn article contains a list of trace events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186265.aspx). This [question sql-server-concise-list-of-trace-flags](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27704/) has a similar scope but differ from as the german msdn article. Below you can find a german list of trace events from the msdn article.

#### What is missing

- I am looking for a complete list of trace events and their description in english.

#### German trace event list

If cou want to import the list below you can create a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TraceEvents](
    [EventTraceID] [int] NULL,
    [Eventname] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [EventDescription] [nvarchar](800) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and add `Insert Into TraceEvents Values` in front of every line from the list

This list was taken from the german article

```
(10,'RPC:Completed','Tritt auf, wenn ein Remoteprozeduraufruf (RPC, Remote Procedure Call) abgeschlossen wurde.');
(11,'RPC:Starting','Tritt auf, wenn ein RPC gestartet wurde.');
(12,'SQL:BatchCompleted','Tritt auf, wenn ein Transact-SQL-Batch abgeschlossen wurde.');
(13,'SQL:BatchStarting','Tritt auf, wenn ein Transact-SQL-Batch gestartet wurde.');
(14,'Audit Login','Tritt auf, wenn sich ein Benutzer erfolgreich an SQL Server anmeldet.');
(15,'Audit Logout','Tritt auf, wenn sich ein Benutzer von SQL Server abmeldet.');
(16,'Attention','Tritt auf, wenn Anforderungsereignisse auftreten, wie z. B. Clientunterbrechungsanforderungen oder das Unterbrechen von Clientverbindungen.');
(17,'ExistingConnection','Erkennt alle Aktivitäten von Benutzern, die mit SQL Server verbunden waren, bevor die Ablaufverfolgung gestartet wurde.');
(18,'Audit Server Starts and Stops','Tritt auf, wenn der SQL Server-Dienststatus geändert wird.');
(19,'DTCTransaction','Verfolgt von Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) koordinierte Transaktionen zwischen zwei oder mehr Datenbanken nach.');
(20,'Audit Login Failed','Zeigt an, dass beim Anmeldeversuch an SQL Server durch einen Client ein Fehler aufgetreten ist.');
(21,'EventLog','Zeigt an, dass Ereignisse im Windows-Anwendungsprotokoll protokolliert wurden.');
(22,'ErrorLog','Zeigt an, dass Fehlerereignisse im SQL Server-Fehlerprotokoll protokolliert wurden.');
(23,'Lock:Released','Kennzeichnet, dass eine Sperre auf einer Ressource, wie z. B. einer Seite, freigegeben wurde.');
(24,'Lock:Acquired','Kennzeichnet den Erhalt einer Sperre auf einer Ressource, z. B. einer Datenseite.');
(25,'Lock:Deadlock','Kennzeichnet, dass sich zwei gleichzeitige Transaktionen gegenseitig blockiert haben, indem sie versucht haben, inkompatible Sperren auf Ressourcen zu erhalten, die sich im Besitz der jeweils anderen Transaktion befinden.');
(26,'Lock:Cancel','Kennzeichnet, dass der Erhalt einer Sperre auf einer Ressource abgebrochen wurde (z. B. aufgrund eines Deadlocks).');
(27,'Lock:Timeout','Kennzeichnet, dass für die Anforderung für eine Sperre auf einer Ressource, wie z. B. einer Seite, ein Timeout aufgetreten ist, da eine andere Transaktion eine blockierende Sperre für die angeforderte Ressource aufrechterhält. Das Timeout wird durch die @@LOCK_TIMEOUT-Funktion bestimmt und kann mit der SET LOCK_TIMEOUT-Anweisung festgelegt werden.');
(28,'Degree of Parallelism-Ereignis (7.0 Insert)','Tritt auf, bevor eine SELECT-, INSERT- oder UPDATE-Anweisung ausgeführt wird.');
(29,'Reserviert','Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Ereignis 28.');
(30,'Reserviert','Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Ereignis 28.');
(31,'Reserviert','Verwenden Sie stattdessen das Ereignis 28.');
(32,'Reserviert','Reserviert');
(33,'Exception','Zeigt an, dass in SQL Server eine Ausnahme aufgetreten ist.');
(34,'SP:CacheMiss','Zeigt an, dass eine gespeicherte Prozedur nicht im Prozedurcache gefunden wurde.');
(35,'SP:CacheInsert','Zeigt an, dass ein Element in den Prozedurcache eingefügt wurde.');
(36,'SP:CacheRemove','Zeigt an, dass ein Element aus dem Prozedurcache entfernt wurde.');
(37,'SP:Recompile','Zeigt an, dass eine gespeicherte Prozedur neu kompiliert wurde.');
(38,'SP:CacheHit','Zeigt an, dass eine gespeicherte Prozedur im Prozedurcache gefunden wurde.');
(39,'Als veraltet markiert','Als veraltet markiert');
(40,'SQL:StmtStarting','Tritt auf, wenn eine Transact-SQL-Anweisung gestartet wurde.');
(41,'SQL:StmtCompleted','Tritt auf, wenn eine Transact-SQL-Anweisung abgeschlossen wurde.');
(42,'SP:Starting','Zeigt an, dass eine gespeicherte Prozedur gestartet wurde.');
(43,'SP:Completed','Zeigt an, dass eine gespeicherte Prozedur abgeschlossen wurde.');
(44,'SP:StmtStarting','Zeigt an, dass die Ausführung einer Transact-SQL-Anweisung in einer gespeicherten Prozedur gestartet wurde.');
(45,'SP:StmtCompleted','Zeigt an, dass die Ausführung einer Transact-SQL-Anweisung in einer gespeicherten Prozedur abgeschlossen wurde.');
(46,'Object:Created','Zeigt an, dass ein Objekt erstellt wurde, z. B. durch eine CREATE INDEX-, CREATE TABLE- oder CREATE DATABASE-Anweisung.');
(47,'Object:Deleted','Zeigt an, dass ein Objekt gelöscht wurde, z. B. durch eine DROP INDEX- oder DROP TABLE-Anweisung.');
(48,'Reserviert','Reserviert');
(49,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(50,'SQL Transaction','Verfolgt die Transact-SQL-Anweisungen BEGIN, COMMIT, SAVE und ROLLBACK TRANSACTION nach.');
(51,'Scan:Started','Zeigt an, dass ein Tabellen- oder Indexscan gestartet wurde.');
(52,'Scan:Stopped','Zeigt an, dass ein Tabellen- oder Indexscan beendet wurde.');
(53,'CursorOpen','Zeigt an, dass ein Cursor für eine Transact-SQL-Anweisung durch ODBC, OLE DB oder DB-Library.geöffnet wird.');
(54,'TransactionLog','Verfolgt nach, wenn Transaktionen in das Transaktionsprotokoll geschrieben werden.');
(55,'Hash Warning','Zeigt an, dass ein Hashvorgang (z. B. Hashjoin, Hashaggregat, Hashvereinigung, Hash-Distinct), der nicht auf einer Pufferpartition durchgeführt wird, nach einem Alternativplan durchgeführt wird. Dies kann aufgrund der Rekursionstiefe, einer Datendrehung (data skew), der Ablaufverfolgungsflags oder der Bitzählung vorkommen.');
(56,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(57,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(58,'Auto Stats','Zeigt an, dass ein automatisches Update der Indexstatistiken aufgetreten ist.');
(59,'Lock:Deadlock Chain','Wird für jedes der Ereignisse erstellt, die zu dem Deadlock führen.');
(60,'Lock:Escalation','Zeigt an, dass eine differenziertere Sperre in eine gröbere Sperre konvertiert wurde (z. B. eine Seitensperre wurde zu einer TABLE- oder HoBT-Sperre ausgeweitet oder in eine solche konvertiert).');
(61,'OLE DB Errors','Zeigt einen OLE DB-Fehler an.');
(62,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(63,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(64,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(65,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(66,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(67,'Execution Warnings','Zeigt alle Warnungen an, die während der Ausführung einer SQL Server-Anweisung oder einer gespeicherten Prozedur aufgetreten sind.');
(68,'Showplan Text (Unencoded)','Zeigt die Planstruktur der Transact-SQL-Anweisung an, die gerade ausgeführt wird.');
(69,'Sort Warnings','Zeigt Sortiervorgänge an, für die der Arbeitsspeicher nicht ausreicht. Sortiervorgänge, die die Indexerstellung beinhalten, sind nicht eingeschlossen, sondern nur Sortiervorgänge mit einer Abfrage (z. B. eine ORDER BY-Klausel in einer SELECT-Anweisung).');
(70,'CursorPrepare','Zeigt an, wenn die Verwendung eines Cursors für eine Transact-SQL-Anweisung durch ODBC, OLE DB oder DB-Library vorbereitet wird.');
(71,'Prepare SQL','ODBC, OLE DB oder DB-Library hat mindestens eine Transact-SQL-Anweisung für die Verwendung vorbereitet.');
(72,'Exec Prepared SQL','ODBC, OLE DB oder DB-Library hat mindestens eine vorbereitete Transact-SQL-Anweisung ausgeführt.');
(73,'Unprepare SQL','ODBC, OLE DB oder DB-Library hat die Vorbereitung mindestens einer Transact-SQL-Anweisung aufgehoben (gelöscht).');
(74,'CursorExecute','Ein Cursor, der zuvor für eine Transact-SQL-Anweisung durch ODBC, OLE DB oder DB-Library vorbereitet wurde, wird ausgeführt.');
(75,'CursorRecompile','Ein für eine Transact-SQL-Anweisung durch ODBC oder DB-Library geöffneter Cursor wurde entweder direkt oder aufgrund einer Schemaänderung neu kompiliert. Wird für ANSI- sowie Nicht-ANSI-Cursor ausgelöst.');
(76,'CursorImplicitConversion','Ein Cursor für eine Transact-SQL-Anweisung wird von SQL Server von einem Typ in einen anderen Typ konvertiert. Wird für ANSI- sowie Nicht-ANSI-Cursor ausgelöst.');
(77,'CursorUnprepare','Die Vorbereitung eines Cursors für eine Transact-SQL-Anweisung wurde durch ODBC, OLE DB oder DB-Library aufgehoben (gelöscht).');
(78,'CursorClose','Ein Cursor, der zuvor für eine Transact-SQL-Anweisung durch ODBC, OLE DB oder DB-Library geöffnet wurde, wird geschlossen.');
(79,'Missing Column Statistics','Spaltenstatistiken, die vom Optimierer hätten verwendet werden können, sind nicht verfügbar.');
(80,'Missing Join Predicate','Eine Abfrage wird ausgeführt, die kein Joinprädikat aufweist. Dies könnte zu einer langen Ausführungszeit für die Abfrage führen.');
(81,'Server Memory Change','Die Speicherauslastung von SQL Server ist über 1 MB oder 5 % des maximal zulässigen Serverarbeitsspeichers (je nachdem, welcher Wert größer ist) gestiegen bzw. gesunken.');
(82,'Vom Benutzer konfigurierbar (0 -9)','Vom Benutzer definierte Ereignisdaten.');
(83,'Vom Benutzer konfigurierbar (0 -9)','Vom Benutzer definierte Ereignisdaten.');
(84,'Vom Benutzer konfigurierbar (0 -9)','Vom Benutzer definierte Ereignisdaten.');
(85,'Vom Benutzer konfigurierbar (0 -9)','Vom Benutzer definierte Ereignisdaten.');
(86,'Vom Benutzer konfigurierbar (0 -9)','Vom Benutzer definierte Ereignisdaten.');
(87,'Vom Benutzer konfigurierbar (0 -9)','Vom Benutzer definierte Ereignisdaten.');
(88,'Vom Benutzer konfigurierbar (0 -9)','Vom Benutzer definierte Ereignisdaten.');
(89,'Vom Benutzer konfigurierbar (0 -9)','Vom Benutzer definierte Ereignisdaten.');
(90,'Vom Benutzer konfigurierbar (0 -9)','Vom Benutzer definierte Ereignisdaten.');
(91,'Vom Benutzer konfigurierbar (0 -9)','Vom Benutzer definierte Ereignisdaten.');
(92,'Data File Auto Grow','Zeigt an, dass eine Protokolldatei automatisch vom Server erweitert wurde.');
(93,'Log File Auto Grow','Zeigt an, dass eine Protokolldatei automatisch vom Server erweitert wurde.');
(94,'Data File Auto Shrink','Zeigt an, dass eine Datendatei automatisch vom Server verkleinert wurde.');
(95,'Log File Auto Shrink','Zeigt an, dass eine Protokolldatei automatisch vom Server verkleinert wurde.');
(96,'Showplan Text','Zeigt die Abfrageplanstruktur des Abfrageoptimierers für die SQL-Anweisung an. Beachten Sie, dass die TextData-Spalte nicht den Showplan für dieses Ereignis enthält.');
(97,'Showplan All','Zeigt den Abfrageplan mit vollständigen Kompilierzeitinformationen für die SQL-Anweisung an, die gerade ausgeführt wird. Beachten Sie, dass die TextData-Spalte nicht den Showplan für dieses Ereignis enthält.');
(98,'Showplan Statistics Profile','Zeigt den Abfrageplan mit vollständigen Laufzeitinformationen für die SQL-Anweisung an, die gerade ausgeführt wird. Beachten Sie, dass die TextData-Spalte nicht den Showplan für dieses Ereignis enthält.');
(99,'Reserviert.','Reserviert');
(100,'RPC Output Parameter','Erzeugt Ausgabewerte der Parameter für jeden RPC.');
(101,'Reserviert','Reserviert');
(102,'Audit Database Scope GDR','Wird immer dann ausgelöst, wenn ein Benutzer in SQL Server eine GRANT-, REVOKE- oder DENY-Anweisung für eine Anweisungsberechtigung ausgibt (dies gilt ausschließlich für datenbankspezifische Ereignisse, beispielsweise das Gewähren von Berechtigungen für eine Datenbank).');
(103,'Audit Object GDR Event','Tritt jedes Mal dann auf, wenn GRANT, DENY oder REVOKE für eine Objektberechtigung von einem Benutzer in SQL Server eingegeben wird.');
(104,'Audit AddLogin Event','Tritt auf, wenn ein SQL Server-Anmeldename hinzugefügt oder entfernt wird; wird für sp_addlogin und sp_droplogin verwendet.');
(105,'Audit Login GDR Event','Tritt auf, wenn ein Windows-Anmeldename hinzugefügt oder entfernt wird; wird für sp_grantlogin, sp_revokelogin und sp_denylogin verwendet.');
(106,'Audit Login Change Property Event','Tritt auf, wenn eine Eigenschaft eines Anmeldenamens, außer Kennwörtern, geändert wird; wird für sp_defaultdb und sp_defaultlanguage verwendet.');
(107,'Audit Login Change Password Event','Tritt auf, wenn das Kennwort für einen SQL Server-Anmeldenamen geändert wird. Kennwörter werden nicht aufgezeichnet.');
(108,'Audit Add Login to Server Role Event','Tritt auf, wenn einer festen Serverrolle ein Anmeldename hinzugefügt oder von ihr entfernt wird; wird für sp_addsrvrolemember und sp_dropsrvrolemember verwendet.');
(109,'Audit Add DB User Event','Tritt auf, wenn ein Anmeldename als ein Datenbankbenutzer (Windows oder SQL Server) einer Datenbank hinzugefügt oder aus ihr entfernt wird; wird für sp_grantdbaccess, sp_revokedbaccess, sp_adduser und sp_dropuser verwendet.');
(110,'Audit Add Member to DB Role Event','Tritt auf, wenn einer Datenbank ein Anmeldename als Datenbankbenutzer (fest oder benutzerdefiniert) hinzugefügt oder aus ihr entfernt wird; wird für sp_addrolemember, sp_droprolemember und sp_changegroup verwendet.');
(111,'Audit Add Role Event','Tritt auf, wenn einer Datenbank ein Anmeldename als Datenbankbenutzer hinzugefügt oder aus ihr entfernt wird; wird für sp_addrole und sp_droprole verwendet.');
(112,'Audit App Role Change Password Event','Tritt auf, wenn ein Kennwort für eine Anwendungsrolle geändert wird.');
(113,'Audit Statement Permission Event','Tritt auf, wenn eine Anweisungsberechtigung, wie z. B. CREATE TABLE, verwendet wird.');
(114,'Audit Schema Object Access Event','Tritt auf, wenn eine Objektberechtigung, wie z. B. SELECT, verwendet wird, unabhängig vom Erfolg.');
(115,'Audit Backup/Restore Event','Tritt auf, wenn ein BACKUP- oder RESTORE-Befehl ausgegeben wird.');
(116,'Audit DBCC Event','Tritt auf, wenn DBCC-Befehle ausgegeben werden.');
(117,'Audit Change Audit Event','Tritt auf, wenn Änderungen an der Überwachung für die Ablaufverfolgung vorgenommen werden.');
(118,'Audit Object Derived Permission Event','Tritt auf, wenn CREATE-, ALTER- und DROP-Objektbefehle ausgegeben werden.');
(119,'OLEDB Call Event','Tritt auf, wenn für verteilte Abfragen und remote gespeicherte Prozeduren Aufrufe des OLE DB-Anbieters ausgegeben werden.');
(120,'OLEDB QueryInterface Event','Tritt auf, wenn für verteilte Abfragen und remote gespeicherte Prozeduren OLE DB-Aufrufe für QueryInterface ausgegeben werden.');
(121,'OLEDB DataRead Event','Tritt auf, wenn ein Datenanforderungsaufruf an den OLE DB-Anbieter ausgegeben wird.');
(122,'Showplan XML','Tritt auf, wenn eine SQL-Anweisung ausgeführt wird. Schließen Sie dieses Ereignis mit ein, um Showplanoperatoren anzugeben. Jedes Ereignis wird in einem wohlgeformten XML-Dokument gespeichert. Beachten Sie, dass die Binary-Spalte für dieses Ereignis den codierten Showplan enthält. Verwenden Sie SQL Server Profiler, um die Ablaufverfolgung zu öffnen und den Showplan anzuzeigen.');
(123,'SQL:FullTextQuery','Tritt auf, wenn eine Volltextabfrage ausgeführt wird.');
(124,'Broker:Conversation','Meldet den Fortschritt einer Service Broker-Konversation.');
(125,'Deprecation Announcement','Tritt auf, wenn Sie eine Funktion verwenden, die aus einer zukünftigen Version von SQL Server entfernt wird.');
(126,'Deprecation Final Support','Tritt auf, wenn Sie eine Funktion verwenden, die aus der nächsten Hauptversion von SQL Server entfernt wird.');
(127,'Exchange Spill Event','Tritt auf, wenn Kommunikationspuffer in einem parallelen Abfrageplan vorübergehend in die tempdb-Datenbank geschrieben wurden.');
(128,'Audit Database Management Event','Tritt auf, wenn eine Datenbank erstellt, geändert oder gelöscht wird.');
(129,'Audit Database Object Management Event','Tritt auf, wenn eine CREATE-, ALTER- oder DROP-Anweisung für Datenbankobjekte, wie z. B. Schemas, ausgeführt wird.');
(130,'Audit Database Principal Management Event','Tritt auf, wenn Prinzipale, wie z. B. Benutzer, in einer Datenbank erstellt oder geändert bzw. aus einer Datenbank gelöscht werden.');
(131,'Audit Schema Object Management Event','Tritt auf, wenn Serverobjekte erstellt, geändert oder gelöscht werden.');
(132,'Audit Server Principal Impersonation Event','Tritt auf, wenn es einen Identitätswechsel im Serverbereich gibt, wie z. B. bei EXECUTE AS LOGIN.');
(133,'Audit Database Principal Impersonation Event','Tritt auf, wenn im Datenbankbereich ein Identitätswechsel auftritt, wie z. B. EXECUTE AS USER oder SETUSER.');
(134,'Audit Server Object Take Ownership Event','Tritt auf, wenn im Serverbereich der Besitzer für Objekte geändert wird.');
(135,'Audit Database Object Take Ownership Event','Tritt auf, wenn im Datenbankbereich der Besitzer für Objekte geändert wird.');
(136,'Broker:Conversation Group','Tritt auf, wenn von Service Broker eine neue Konversationsgruppe erstellt oder eine vorhandene Konversationsgruppe gelöscht wird.');
(137,'Blocked Process Report','Tritt auf, wenn ein Prozess länger als einen festgelegten Zeitraum blockiert ist. Schließt keine Systemprozesse oder Prozesse ein, die auf Ressourcen warten, für die keine Deadlocks erkannt werden können. Verwenden Sie sp_configure, um den Schwellenwert und die Häufigkeit der Berichtgenerierung zu konfigurieren.');
(138,'Broker:Connection','Gibt den Status einer Transportverbindung an, die von Service Broker verwaltet wird.');
(139,'Broker:Forwarded Message Sent','Tritt auf, wenn von Service Broker eine Nachricht weitergeleitet wird.');
(140,'Broker:Forwarded Message Dropped','Tritt auf, wenn von Service Broker eine Nachricht gelöscht wird, die weitergeleitet werden sollte.');
(141,'Broker:Message Classify','Tritt auf, wenn von Service Broker das Routing für eine Nachricht bestimmt wird.');
(142,'Broker:Transmission','Zeigt an, dass auf der Transportebene von Service Broker Fehler aufgetreten sind. Die Fehlernummer und Statuswerte kennzeichnen die Fehlerquelle.');
(143,'Broker:Queue Disabled','Zeigt an, dass eine beschädigte Nachricht erkannt wurde, weil in einer Service Broker-Warteschlange fünf Transaktionsrollbacks aufeinander folgten. Das Ereignis enthält die Datenbank-ID und die Warteschlangen-ID der Warteschlange mit der beschädigten Nachricht.');
(144,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(145,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(146,'Showplan XML Statistics Profile','Tritt auf, wenn eine SQL-Anweisung ausgeführt wird. Identifiziert die Showplanoperatoren und zeigt vollständige Kompilierzeitdaten an. Beachten Sie, dass die Binary-Spalte für dieses Ereignis den codierten Showplan enthält. Verwenden Sie SQL Server Profiler, um die Ablaufverfolgung zu öffnen und den Showplan anzuzeigen.');
(148,'Deadlock Graph','Tritt auf, wenn der Versuch, eine Sperre zu aktivieren, abgebrochen wird, da der Versuch Teil eines Deadlocks war und als Deadlockopfer ausgewählt wurde. Stellt eine XML-Beschreibung eines Deadlocks bereit.');
(149,'Broker:Remote Message Acknowledgement','Tritt auf, wenn von Service Broker eine Nachrichtenbestätigung gesendet oder empfangen wird.');
(150,'Trace File Close','Tritt auf, wenn eine Ablaufverfolgungsdatei beim Rollover für Ablaufverfolgungsdateien geschlossen wird.');
(151,'Reserviert','Reserviert');
(152,'Audit Change Database Owner','Tritt auf, wenn ALTER AUTHORIZATION verwendet wird, um den Besitzer einer Datenbank zu ändern, und die entsprechenden Berechtigungen geprüft werden.');
(153,'Audit Schema Object Take Ownership Event','Tritt auf, wenn ALTER AUTHORIZATION verwendet wird, um einem Objekt einen Besitzer zuzuweisen, und die Berechtigungen dafür geprüft werden.');
(154,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(155,'FT:Crawl Started','Tritt auf, wenn eine Volltextdurchforstung (Auffüllung) gestartet wird. Wird verwendet, um zu prüfen, ob eine Durchforstungsanforderung von Arbeitstasks abgerufen wird.');
(156,'FT:Crawl Stopped','Tritt auf, wenn eine Volltextdurchforstung (Auffüllung) beendet wird. Die Beendigung kann bei einem erfolgreichen Abschließen des Durchforstungsvorgangs oder bei einem schwerwiegenden Fehler erfolgen.');
(157,'FT:Crawl Aborted','Tritt auf, wenn bei einer Volltextdurchforstung eine Ausnahme festgestellt wird. In der Regel wird die Volltextdurchforstung dadurch angehalten.');
(158,'Audit Broker Conversation','Gibt Überwachungsmeldungen an, die mit der Dialogsicherheit von Service Broker verbunden sind.');
(159,'Audit Broker Login','Meldet Überwachungsmeldungen, die mit der Transportsicherheit von Service Broker verbunden sind.');
(160,'Broker:Message Undeliverable','Tritt auf, wenn von Service Broker eine empfangene Nachricht nicht beibehalten werden kann, die an einen Dienst weitergeleitet werden sollte.');
(161,'Broker:Corrupted Message','Tritt auf, wenn von Service Broker eine beschädigte Nachricht empfangen wird.');
(162,'User Error Message','Zeigt Fehlermeldungen an, die für Benutzer im Falle eines Fehlers oder einer Ausnahme angezeigt werden.');
(163,'Broker:Activation','Tritt auf, wenn eine Warteschlangenüberwachung eine gespeicherte Aktivierungsprozedur startet oder eine QUEUE_ACTIVATION-Benachrichtigung sendet oder wenn eine gespeicherte Aktivierungsprozedur, die von einer Warteschlangenüberwachung gestartet wurde, beendet wird.');
(164,'Object:Altered','Tritt auf, wenn ein Datenbankobjekt geändert wird.');
(165,'Performance statistics','Tritt auf, wenn ein kompilierter Abfrageplan zum ersten Mal zwischengespeichert, erneut kompiliert oder aus dem Plancache gelöscht wird.');
(166,'SQL:StmtRecompile','Tritt auf, wenn eine erneute Kompilierung auf Anweisungsebene durchgeführt wird.');
(167,'Database Mirroring State Change','Tritt auf, wenn sich der Status einer gespiegelten Datenbank ändert.');
(168,'Showplan XML For Query Compile','Tritt auf, wenn eine SQL-Anweisung kompiliert wird. Zeigt die vollständigen Kompilierzeitdaten an. Beachten Sie, dass die Binary-Spalte für dieses Ereignis den codierten Showplan enthält. Verwenden Sie SQL Server Profiler, um die Ablaufverfolgung zu öffnen und den Showplan anzuzeigen.');
(169,'Showplan All For Query Compile','Tritt auf, wenn eine SQL-Anweisung kompiliert wird. Zeigt die vollständigen Kompilierzeitdaten an. Wird verwendet, um Showplanoperatoren anzugeben.');
(170,'Audit Server Scope GDR Event','Gibt an, dass im Serverbereich ein Ereignis zum Erteilen, Aufheben oder Verweigern von Berechtigungen aufgetreten ist, wie z. B. das Erstellen eines Anmeldenamens.');
(171,'Audit Server Object GDR Event','Gibt an, dass ein Ereignis zum Erteilen, Aufheben oder Verweigern für ein Schemaobjekt, wie z. B. eine Tabelle oder Funktion, aufgetreten ist.');
(172,'Audit Database Object GDR Event','Gibt an, dass ein Ereignis zum Erteilen, Aufheben oder Verweigern für Datenbankobjekte, wie z. B. Assemblys und Schemas, aufgetreten ist.');
(173,'Audit Server Operation Event','Tritt auf, wenn Sicherheitsüberwachungsvorgänge verwendet werden, wie z. B. das Ändern von Einstellungen, Ressourcen, des externen Zugriffs oder von Berechtigungen.');
(175,'Audit Server Alter Trace Event','Tritt auf, wenn eine Anweisung die ALTER TRACE-Berechtigung überprüft.');
(176,'Audit Server Object Management Event','Tritt auf, wenn Serverobjekte erstellt, geändert oder gelöscht werden.');
(177,'Audit Server Principal Management Event','Tritt auf, wenn Serverprinzipale erstellt, geändert oder gelöscht werden.');
(178,'Audit Database Operation Event','Tritt auf, wenn Datenbankvorgänge auftreten, wie z. B. CHECKPOINT oder SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS.');
(180,'Audit Database Object Access Event','Tritt auf beim Zugriff auf Datenbankobjekte, wie z. B. Schemas.');
(181,'TM: Begin Tran starting','Tritt auf, wenn eine BEGIN TRANSACTION-Anforderung gestartet wird.');
(182,'TM: Begin Tran completed','Tritt auf, wenn eine BEGIN TRANSACTION-Anforderung abgeschlossen wird.');
(183,'TM: Promote Tran starting','Tritt auf, wenn eine PROMOTE TRANSACTION-Anforderung gestartet wird.');
(184,'TM: Promote Tran completed','Tritt auf, wenn eine PROMOTE TRANSACTION-Anforderung abgeschlossen wird.');
(185,'TM: Commit Tran starting','Tritt auf, wenn eine COMMIT TRANSACTION-Anforderung gestartet wird.');
(186,'TM: Commit Tran completed','Tritt auf, wenn eine COMMIT TRANSACTION-Anforderung abgeschlossen wird.');
(187,'TM: Rollback Tran starting','Tritt auf, wenn eine ROLLBACK TRANSACTION-Anforderung gestartet wird.');
(188,'TM: Rollback Tran completed','Tritt auf, wenn eine ROLLBACK TRANSACTION-Anforderung abgeschlossen wird.');
(189,'Lock:Timeout (Timeout > 0)','Tritt auf bei einer Zeitüberschreitung für eine Anforderung einer Sperre auf eine Ressource, wie z. B. eine Seite.');
(190,'Progress Report: Online Index Operation','Meldet den Fortschritt einer Onlineindexerstellung, während der Erstellungsprozess ausgeführt wird.');
(191,'TM: Save Tran starting','Tritt auf, wenn eine SAVE TRANSACTION-Anforderung gestartet wird.');
(192,'TM: Save Tran completed','Tritt auf, wenn eine SAVE TRANSACTION-Anforderung abgeschlossen wird.');
(193,'Background Job Error','Tritt auf, wenn ein Hintergrundauftrag fehlerbedingt beendet wurde.');
(194,'OLEDB Provider Information','Tritt auf, wenn eine verteilte Abfrage ausgeführt wird und Informationen sammelt, die sich auf die Anbieterverbindung beziehen.');
(195,'Mount Tape','Tritt auf, wenn eine Anforderung zur Bandeinlegung empfangen wird.');
(196,'Assembly Load','Tritt auf, wenn eine Anforderung zum Laden einer CLR-Assembly auftritt.');
(197,'Reserviert.','Reserviert.');
(198,'XQuery Static Type','Tritt auf, wenn ein XQuery-Ausdruck ausgeführt wird. Diese Ereignisklasse stellt den statischen Typ des XQuery-Ausdrucks bereit.');
(199,'Abonnement','Tritt auf, wenn kein Abonnement für die Registrierung einer Abfrage möglich ist. Die TextData-Spalte enthält Informationen zum Ereignis.');
(200,'QN: parameter table','Informationen zu aktiven Abonnements werden in internen Parametertabellen gespeichert. Diese Ereignisklasse tritt dann auf, wenn eine Parametertabelle angelegt oder gelöscht wird. In der Regel werden diese Tabellen erstellt oder gelöscht, wenn die Datenbank neu gestartet wird. Die TextData-Spalte enthält Informationen zum Ereignis.');
(201,'template','Eine Abfragevorlage stellt eine Klasse von Abonnementabfragen dar. In der Regel sind Abfragen derselben Klasse mit Ausnahme der Parameterwerte identisch. Diese Ereignisklasse tritt dann auf, wenn eine neue Abfrageanforderung zu einer bereits vorhanden Klasse (Match), einer neue Klasse (Create) oder einer Klasse vom Typ Drop gehört, die Vorlagencleanups für Abfrageklassen ohne aktive Abonnements angibt. Die TextData-Spalte enthält Informationen zum Ereignis.');
(202,'QN: dynamics','Verfolgt interne Aktivitäten von Abfragebenachrichtigungen nach. Die TextData-Spalte enthält Informationen zum Ereignis.');
(212,'Bitmapwarnung','Zeigt an, wenn Bitmap-Filter in einer Abfrage deaktiviert wurden.');
(213,'Database Suspect Data Page','Gibt an, wenn der Tabelle suspect_pages in msdb eine Seite hinzugefügt wird.');
(214,'CPU threshold exceeded','Zeigt an, dass die Ressourcenkontrolle erkannt hat, dass eine Abfrage den CPU-Grenzwert (REQUEST_MAX_CPU_TIME_SEC) überschritten hat.');
(215,'Zeigt an, dass die Ausführung eines LOGON-Triggers oder einer Klassifizierungsfunktion der Ressourcenkontrolle beginnt.','Zeigt an, dass die Ausführung eines LOGON-Triggers oder einer Klassifizierungsfunktion der Ressourcenkontrolle beginnt.');
(216,'PreConnect:Completed','Zeigt an, dass die Ausführung eines LOGON-Triggers oder einer Klassifizierungsfunktion der Ressourcenkontrolle beendet wird.');
(217,'Plan Guide Successful','Zeigt an, dass SQL Server erfolgreich einen Ausführungsplan für eine Abfrage oder einen Batch mit einer Planhinweisliste erzeugt hat.');
(218,'Plan Guide Unsuccessful','Zeigt an, dass SQL Server keinen Ausführungsplan für eine Abfrage oder einen Batch mit einer Planhinweisliste erzeugen konnte. SQL Server hat versucht, einen Ausführungsplan für diese Abfrage oder den Batch zu generieren, ohne die Planhinweisliste anzuwenden. Eine ungültige Planhinweisliste ist möglicherweise die Ursache dieses Problems. Die neue Systemfunktion "sys.fn_validate_plan_guide" kann zur Überprüfung einer Planhinweisliste verwendet werden.');
(235,'Audit Fulltext','Audit Fulltext');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this list from Microsoft:

[sp_trace_setevent (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186265.aspx)

You can also query the [`sys.trace_events`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189793.aspx) catalog view, which returns `trace_event_id, category_id, name`, but no description.